# fixed header slidedown effect not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implent a fixed header similar to amazon or walmart.
I am using the following code

```
    <script>

$(window).scroll(function(){
         var sticky = $('#pts-mainnav')
     var sticky2 = $('#pts-verticalmenu'),
         scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 220){
            sticky.slideDown('2000', "swing");
            sticky.addClass('fixed');
        sticky2.addClass('dropdown-fixed');
    $('#b').show();
    $('#fixed-usermenu').show();
    $('#fixed-verticalmenuid').show();
    $("#categoriesname").html("&nbsp;");
        }else{
            sticky.removeClass('fixed');
        sticky2.removeClass('dropdown-fixed');
    $('#b').hide();
    $('#fixed-usermenu').hide();
    $('#fixed-verticalmenuid').hide();
    $("#categoriesname").html("Όλα τα προϊόντα");
            sticky.removeAttr("style");
        sticky.removeAttr("class"); 
        }
    });


    </script>
```

and then the following .css

```
@media all and (min-width: 780px){
    .fixed {
      position:fixed; 
      top:0; 
      z-index:9999; 
      width:100%; 
      max-width:1250px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #333333;
      box-shadow: 0 0 3px #333333;
    }
    .dropdown-fixed {width:68px;}
}
```

And althoug the fixed header is working I can not ajust the dropdown effect to behave like amazon or walmart.

Is the code correct?
I would be realy happy if someone can help me

You can see the header in action at the following url [here](http://www.multitec.gr/presta3/)

Answer (score 0):

After playing around and some hints from the irc channel: All I need to add was top:-95px; to the pts-mainnav part of the .css